# JPA: Many to many relationship - JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm having trouble with a many to many relation with JPA.
My code looks as follows:

The Sensor class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sensor")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Sensor {
    @Id
    private long chipId;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "sensor")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Set<Link> userLinks;
    private String firmwareVersion;
    private long creationTimestamp;
    private String notes;
    private long lastMeasurementTimestamp;
    private long lastEditTimestamp;
    private double gpsLatitude;
    private double gpsLongitude;
    private double gpsAltitude;
    private String country;
    private String city;
    private boolean indoor;
    private boolean published;
}
```

The user class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private Set<Link> sensorLinks;
    private int role;
    private int status;
    private long creationTimestamp;
    private long lastEditTimestamp;
}
```

And the Link class (relation class):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "link")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Link {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    @MapsId("user_id")
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "sensor_id")
    @MapsId("sensor_id")
    private Sensor sensor;

    private boolean owner;
    private String name;
    private int color;
    private long creationTimestamp;
}
```

The controller:

```
...

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, path = "/user/{email}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ApiOperation(value = "Returns details for one specific user")
public User getUserByEmail(@PathVariable("email") String email) {
    return userRepository.findByEmail(email).orElse(null);
}

...
```

The UserRepository:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {

    Optional<User> findByEmail(String email);

    @Modifying
    @Query("UPDATE User u SET u.firstName = ?2, u.lastName = ?3, u.password = ?4, u.role = ?5, u.status = ?6 WHERE u.id = ?1")
    Integer updateUser(int id, String firstName, String lastName, String password, int role, int status);
}
```

I want to achieve, that the user endpoint shows all linked sensors with that particular user.
What I get is only an error message:

> JSON mapping problem:
>   com.chillibits.particulatematterapi.model.db.main.User["sensorLinks"];
>   nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Infinite
>   recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain:
>   com.chillibits.particulatematterapi.model.db.main.User["sensorLinks"])

How can I fix this issue?

Thanks in advance

Marc

------------------------------------ Edit -----------------------------------

According to Abinash Ghosh's answer, I added following DTOs:

UserDto:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UserDto {
    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Set<LinkDto> sensorLinks;
    private int role;
    private int status;
    private long creationTimestamp;
    private long lastEditTimestamp;
}
```

LinkDto:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class LinkDto {
    private Integer id;
    private SensorDto sensor;
    private boolean owner;
    private String name;
    private int color;
    private long creationTimestamp;
}
```

And the mapper (I realized it a bit different, but it should be the same):

```
public UserDto getUserByEmail(@PathVariable("email") String email) {
    User user = userRepository.findByEmail(email).orElse(null);
    return convertToDto(user);
}

private UserDto convertToDto(User user) {
    return mapper.map(user, UserDto.class);
}
```

This leads to following Exception:

```
2020-04-13 14:22:24.383  WARN 8176 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.e.loading.internal.LoadContexts      : HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@68ab57c7<rs=HikariProxyResultSet@2017009664 wrapping Result set representing update count of -1>

1) Error mapping com.chillibits.particulatematterapi.model.db.main.User to com.chillibits.particulatematterapi.model.io.UserDto
1 error] with root cause
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.execSQL(NativeSession.java:1109) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
...
```

Comment: Add your controller and service also to find out your problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Infinite Recursion with Jackson JSON and Hibernate JPA issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325387/infinite-recursion-with-jackson-json-and-hibernate-jpa-issue)

Comment: I already tried `@JsonIgnore`. When I add it for both (sensorLinks and userLinks) it works. I also tried to add `@JsonIgnore` only to userLinks in `Sensor.class`, which doesn't work.

Comment: Remove `private Sensor sensor;` from LinkDTO. Don't use any Enity class again into DTO then it will result same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's working!
This post helped: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57111004/6296634

Seems that you should not use Lombok `@Data` in such cases.

Answer (score 0):

When `User` serialized for the response, all getter methods of `User`'s fields are called. 
So, `User` relational field `sensorLinks`'s getter are also called to set value. This happened recursively. That's cause of infinite recursion.

It's better to not use Entity as a response. Create a DTO class for `User` then map `User` entity value into DTO then send response. **Don't use any Enity class again into DTO then it will result same problem**

For dynamically map one model to another you can use `ModleMapper`

```
public class UserDTO {
   //Fields you want to show in response & don't use enity class 
   private Set<LinkDTO> sensorLinks;
}
public class LinkDTO{
   //Fields you want to show in response &don't use enity class 
}


public User getUserByEmail(@PathVariable("email") String email) {
    User user = userRepository.findByEmail(email).orElse(null);
    UserDTO userDto = merge(user,UserDTO.class)
    return userDto;
}

public static <T> void merge(T source, T target) {
    ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
    modelMapper.getConfiguration().setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.STRICT);
    modelMapper.map(source, target);
  }
```

Comment: That doesn't work either. I added the changes to the question above. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Remove `private Sensor sensor;` from LinkDTO or if you need this make another DTO

Comment: If you use entity in dto then again recursive  fetching occurs

Comment: I solved it! See my answer above. Indeed, thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you try to remove `private Sensor sensor;` this ? It will also work. Using lombok is big safe in development